# Chrome Extension webRequest.onBeforeRequest Cancel Page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to create a chrome extension that queries an external source as a reference to block or allow through a particular page. The following is part of my code. I am new to javascript, and scope always seems to be something that screws me up.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {

        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://xxx.xx.xxxx";
        var params = "urlCheck="+encodeString_(details.url);
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                guilt = 0;
                console.log(guilt);
            }else if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 404){
                guilt = 1;
                console.log(guilt);
            }
        }
        http.send(params);

    if(guilt == 1){
        return {cancel: true};
        }else{
        return {cancel: false};
        }

    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"],
     types:["main_frame"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
    );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

Your code does not work as expected because XHR is asynchronous; your `onreadystatechange` is executed after the whole outer function finishes. So `guilt` will be undefined or, worse, stale (from the last request).

For more information, see this canonical question: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

However, if you try to fix this, you'll notice that you can't return a response from within the async handler.

This is intentional: there is no function to pass and then call later (like `sendResponse` in Messaging API), because Chrome *will not wait for you*. You are expected to respond to a blocking call in a deterministic and fast way.

> If the optional `opt_extraInfoSpec` array contains the string `'blocking'` (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled synchronously. That means that the request is blocked **until the callback function returns**.

You *could* try to bypass it by using synchronous XHR calls. That is not a very good idea in general, since loading a remote response takes a long time, and synchronous XHR is considered deprecated. Even though you limited your queries to `"main_frame"` requests, this still adds an uncertain delay to each load.

A proper way to do that would be to load a set of rules from a server and update it periodically, and when a request occurs validate it against this local copy of rules. This is the approach extensions like AdBlock use.